# Django only runs by command line but not in PyCharm

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pycharm, django-2.1

I'm trying to run a Django (version 2.1) project in PyCharm, and the run configurations are properly set to work with the right environment and to use the manage.py file to run the server. At least with other projects in PyCharm I can run without problems. But why I only get the following error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured
```

only when running directly from PyCharm? By command line it runs perfectly fine with the command 'python manage.py runserver'.

Comment: Make sure PyCharm is pointing to the correct settings file would be my guess. Make a blank Django project and see if PyCharm works with the minimal project.

Comment: @zyeek well it seems to work with a generic python configuration. It was not working with the built in Django server that comes with PyCharm professional edition